# Add Function\Sub from another function\sub

Tags: vba, excel

My question may be very foolish. but i would like to know is it possible and how?
from one of the function\sub can i **create** another sub\function.

Example:

```
Sub first()
    x = 10
    if x = 10 Then 
      'Add Another Sub based on the Condition in another module.
       Sub Second()
       End Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

My real problem is i am trying add new sheet in a loop based on some condition. if i am able to add sheet, then i need to create some buttons in another sheet, as well as function for those buttons.
Please help on this.

Comment: See here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx for how to add code programatically in VBA

Comment: writing via VBE is fascinating, but I'd avoid it if possibly. if button function is already known at design time, you could code it and assign to each button action property with fully qualified reference (see below) since subs can be called even if residing in different workbooks. you have two ways: either by adding a the "target" sheet (where button resides) a reference to the "base" workbook (where function resides) or by using the `Run` method (`Application.Run “’BaseMacrosSheet.xlsm’!MacroName”). The former doesn't require the "base" workbook to be open at runtime while the latter does.

Answer (score 1):

By default, my approach would be:

```
Sub first()
    x = 10
    if x = 10 Then 
      'Call Another Sub based on the Condition.
       Call Second()
    End If
End Sub

Sub Second()
' do stuff
End Sub
```

If you are creating new sheets and adding buttons with code behind them, all of the code, button design, etc. should be done. Any customization would be through parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about the *design* of your code. Firstly, you can't put a sub inside another sub, that's just not how it works unfortunately.

What you *can* do is use **scope** and **conditions** to control the flow of your code and make sure that certain parts are only executed when you want them to be.

---

The easiest, and recommended, method is to just write the other sub anyway but only *call* it if a certain condition is met.

```
Public Sub Main_Sub()

Dim x As Integer

x = 11 '// Change x to 5 and the other sub won't run

If x > 10 Then
    Other_Sub
    '// Code execution will resume here once 'Other_Sub' has finished
    MsgBox "Other Sub complete!"
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Other_Sub()

    MsgBox "You're in the other sub now!"

End Sub
```

---

Another way is to simply exit the sub if your condition isn't met, although this is used more for error handling than conditional execution:

```
Public Sub Main_Sub()

Dim x As Integer

x = 11 '// Change x to 5 and the other sub won't run

If x > 10 Then
    Other_Sub
    '// Code execution will resume here once 'Other_Sub' has finished
    MsgBox "Other Sub complete!"
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox "You will only see this message if x was greater than 10!"

End Sub

Private Sub Other_Sub()

    MsgBox "You're in the other sub now!"

End Sub
```

---

One final method could be using labels, and although it's a viable solution I do advise against it because it severely affects the readability and logic of your code:

```
Public Sub Main_Sub()

Dim x As Integer

x = 11 '// Change x to 5 and the other sub won't run

If x < 11 Then GoTo Skip_Other_Sub:

Other_Sub

Skip_Other_Sub:

MsgBox "You will see this regardless of the other sub being run!"

End Sub

Private Sub Other_Sub()

    MsgBox "You're in the other sub now!"

End Sub
```

---

The main point here is that it's better to write *all* of the code that may or may not be needed and call it conditionally rather than trying to create code "on the fly" which is messy at best and requires programmatic access to the VBE which can leave your machine vulnerable if you aren't 100% confident with what you're doing.